# How to convert the variant call format file (.vcf file) into a txt file with R?

Tags: r, vcf-variant-call-format

I would like to convert these 3 lines (from a .vcf file):

```
##bcftools_annotateCommand=annotate -a /mnt/storage/home/gh13047/mr-eve/vcf-reference-datasets/dbsnp/dbsnp.v153.b37.vcf.gz -c ID -o /mnt/storage/private/mrcieu/research/scratch/IGD/data/dev/ukb-d-import/processed/ukb-d-20544_1/ukb-d-20544_1.vcf.gz -O z /mnt/storage/private/mrcieu/research/scratch/IGD/data/dev/ukb-d-import/processed/ukb-d-20544_1/ukb-d-20544_1_data.vcf.gz; Date=Mon Nov 25 15:37:00 2019
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  ukb-d-20544_1
1       692794  rs530212009     CA      C       .       PASS    AF=0.111693     ES:SE:LP:AF:SS:ID       0.000379398:0.000798869:0.197332:0.111693:117706:1_692794_CA_C
```

to a txt.gz file with R:

```
CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  ukb-d-20544_1
1       692794  rs530212009     CA      C       .       PASS    AF=0.111693     ES:SE:LP:AF:SS:ID       0.000379398:0.000798869:0.197332:0.111693:117706:1_692794_CA_C
```

I tried with `MungeSumstats` but it does not work.

Comment: Could you please share your code of what you have tried so far or a reproducible example so that someone could help you out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try the last part of this answer:  https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/21724/15519  _try unzipping and simply replacing .vcf with .txt in the filename_